# ubuntu 23.04 problem installation

Tags: boot

bonjour . apres toutes les etapes correctes pour installer ubuntu depuis une cle bootable qui fonctionne parfaitement et au moment du redemarrage le systeme boot sur mon ancien syteme exploitation et pas sur unbutu . merci

Comment: For most users, following all the steps correctly results in a properly-installed Ubuntu system. The most common reason for a failed install is not completely following the instructions. Shortcut = Fail.

Comment: This is an English question & answer site. If not comfortable with English, I have these in my note. Not sure how active or if still active. https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/ & 
https://www.ubuntu-fr.org/